Wavy Alphabet ScrollBar Android Studio
image here
i have a list of alphabet textviews in a linearLayout. when i touch any alphabets i want wavy like animation to move the position of the texviews just like the picture i have given.its similar to Niagra laucnhers app drawers scroll bar
here is my code. its giving me similar effect but not smooth as that launchers scroll bar.
private fun moveTextViewsToLeft1(index: Int) {
        val adjacentViews = mutableListOf<Pair<View, Float>>()
        val touchedViewTranslationX = -100f
        val neighborTranslationX = -80f
        val extraNeighborTranslationX1 = -45f
        val extraNeighborTranslationX2 = -10f

        // Add touched textView
        val touchedView = getChildAt(index)
        adjacentViews.add(touchedView to touchedViewTranslationX)

        // Add top neighbors
        for (i in index - 1 downTo 0) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            val translationX = when (index - i) {
                1 -> neighborTranslationX
                2 -> extraNeighborTranslationX1
                3 -> extraNeighborTranslationX2
                else -> 0f
            }
            adjacentViews.add(view to translationX)
        }

        // Add bottom neighbors
        for (i in index + 1 until childCount) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            val translationX = when (i - index) {
                1 -> neighborTranslationX
                2 -> extraNeighborTranslationX1
                3 -> extraNeighborTranslationX2
                else -> 0f
            }
            adjacentViews.add(view to translationX)
        }

        val animators = mutableListOf<ObjectAnimator>()
        for ((view, translationXValue) in adjacentViews) {
            val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_X, translationXValue)
            animator.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION
            animator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
            animators.add(animator)
        }

        val set = AnimatorSet()
        set.playTogether(animators as Collection<Animator>?)
        set.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
                isAnimating = true
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                isAnimating = false
            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
                isAnimating = false
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {}
        })
        set.start()
    }


please anyone help me...
